# on showing a canonical isomorphism related to product of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $(E_{i})_{i \in I}$ and $(F_{i})_{i \in I}$ be two families of
$A-$modules. There is a family of linear mappings $f_{i}: E_{i} \to
F_{i}$. By using the universal property, it can be showed that there
exists a unique linear mapping $f: \Pi E_{i} \to \Pi F_{i}$ given by
$f(x_{i}) = (f_{i}(x_{i}))$. How can we show that there is a canonical
isomorphism $$Coim f \to \Pi\ Coim f_{i}$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Induce a map $p:\Pi E_i \rightarrow \Pi E_i/ker (f_i)$ from the canonical projections $p_i:E_i \rightarrow E_i/ker (f_i)$ (like you did with $f$ from the $f_i$); show that $p$ is surjective with kernel equal to $ker(f)$.

Comment: Thanks! To elaborate on the hint:
Let $p:\Pi E_{i} \to \Pi (E_{i}/ker (f_{i}))$ be defined as $p(x) =
(p_{i}(x_{i}))$. If $x \in ker (f)$ then $f(x) = 0$ and thus
$(f_{i}(x_{i})) = 0$ for all $i \in I$. So, $x_{i} \in ker
(f_{i})$. This makes $p(x) = (p_{i}(x_{i})) = (ker (f_{i}))$ and since
$ker (f) = \Pi ker (f_{i})$, $p(x) = ker (f)$ and thus $x \in ker
(p)$. Similarly the other way can be shown. $p$ is surjective since $p_{i}$ are. Hope there are no other gaps. I am following
Bourbaki's text on algebra. Could you please refer to some other
sources as well?

Comment: Just a few spots to clean up: $x \in ker(f) \Rightarrow f(x)=0 \Rightarrow f_i(x_i)=0 \; \forall i \in I \Rightarrow x_i \in ker(f_i) \; \forall i \in I \Rightarrow p_i(x_i)=0 \; \forall i \in I \Rightarrow p(x)=0 \Rightarrow x \in ker(p)$.

Comment: I use the text $\mathit Algebra$ by Thomas W. Hungerford.